# Create Multiple Apks with same project and same package?

Tags: android, apk

I want to create Multiple Apks with same project and same package.

Because i have to install multiple apks in single device with same package, for managing multiple clients.

Google says "you probably need to create separate Android projects for each APK you intend to publish so that you can appropriately develop them separately. But in this way very difficult to manage multiple source codes.

Is there any other way to create Multiple Apks with same project and same package ?

Comment: With same package, it may not be possible

Comment: You can use build flavours in Gradle.

Comment: I answered it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201832/how-to-create-multiple-apks-from-one-project/48783773#48783773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Android Studio and Gradle it is pretty easy to have different apk with small code variation, using [flavors](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants).

(However i advise you to use different product id for each apk. If you don't you will have issue distribute them on Google Play and running them on the same device. Don't worry the link i gave you explain that.)